# Design layout of fitness application?

Tags: android, user-interface, prototype

I am trying to design my android layout based on the prototype I made, the prototype is given below. The area marked in black solid outline is what I am currently working at but have no clue on how to make it? All I have right now is a root view of LinearLayout. Any ideas on how I design the selected area?

[image]

Comment: A little help is appreciated? I have a specific question about the highlighted area.

Comment: Please understand that this is a Q&A site. Ask a precise question, get a precise answer. You can't ask us to design your app UI. We may solve a bug for you or point you in the right direction. We help for specific difficulties, not for a whole UI design.

Comment: Want to design 418 shown layout?? What you tried??

Comment: I have only made the nutrition goals for today textview currently. 
@Vyger:my apologies.

Comment: Apologies aren't needed. You didn't do anything bad to me. ;)

Comment: @Vyger: I was looking for direction as clearly mentioned in my question, never asked for designing the app layout. Clearly i have worked hard on the prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have made sample for you. See if it works

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#f9f9f9"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="418"
                android:textColor="#37c100"
                android:textSize="33sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Calories Remaining"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#c7c7c7" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="#f5f5f5" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="418"
                    android:textColor="#37c100"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="Calories Remaining"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#f5f5f5" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#f5f5f5" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#f5f5f5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Yup exactly what i was looking for, works for me.